# Can we create Batch File to queue the build from TFS server?

Tags: c#, batch-file, tfs

Can we write the Batch file to queue the build from **TFS Server** to any shared location at every night once all the code check in is done, with folder name with date stamp **(queue_20170907)**. can you please help me out.

Comment: How would you judge if all the check in is done or not at every night? Or you just need to queue a build at a specific time such as 3:00 am(every developer is out of work now)?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT yes exactly what you said wanted to queue the build on specific time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **Rest API** to [queue a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build). Set the build number format with date for the corresponding build definition.

This blog--[**Queue TFS/VSTS builds VIA PowerShell**](http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/10/14/queue-tfsvsts-builds-via-powershell/)  shows how to use powershell script to connect to TFS with the appropriate credentials , queue a build , finally retrieve build artifacts and store the package.

You could also use some 3rd-party extension such as [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) to queue any build definitios. If you need to queue other builds at a specific time at every night, just set a [scheduled trigger](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#scheduled).

[image]

Comment: wanted to create the batch file and the link you have share I didn't found related creation to batch file for queuing the build. Can we create the batch file for same ?

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Afraid not. There is not any command  could trigger the tfs build in the batch file. Did you have to use batch files to do this ? And since wanted to queue the build on specific time, you could directly set a **Scheduled** build through the triggers in the build definition.

Comment: @ Patrick-MSFT Thanks but I am not aware of the how to trigger in the build definition if you can help me out that will be great.

Comment: @UnmeshGhatbandhe Which build are you using XAML or vNext? There is an option in your build definition called trigger. You could check the Scheduled  button under the trigger, then just need to select when to build , the day in the week and the time in a day, you could also set time zone, branch filters. Then when time is matched, tfs will auto trigger the build. More detail steps please refer this tutorial from MSFT:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#scheduled

Answer (score 3):

I just make a .bat file, and use tfsbuild statements.

```
tfsbuild start http://tfs.you.com:8080/tfs/MYPC XYZ Release_Build.v1.0.9 /priority:Normal /requestedfor:TFSSERVICE
```

You can schedule it to run, or create a build definition that calls the batch file to run at a certain time each night.